# Convert HTML5 to Lightning Web Component

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

We have a small team of developpers and designers working on a same project. Our designers are willing to feed us pure HTML5 files and we, Salesforce developpers, need to convert that to the new Lightning Web Components : [see](https://lwc.dev/). So we are looking for an effective and fast way to do that.

Is there any solution ? Knowing that the HTML files are quite complex and generated from Adobe InDesign projects. The best solution would be an automatic way to do that.

Thank you,

Comment: What does it mean to you to convert an HTML5 file to a Lightning Web Component? What are the HTML5 files - are they representative of a UI that is meant to interact with your CRM data? As asked, I think the question is too broad to have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the HTML is all static then just copy and paste the HTML inside template tags

Answer (score 0):

You'll anyway need to design using component based architecture instead of adding all functionality and UI in huge components.

Start thinking what can be made reusable and use the UI designs to create your templates.